# Object doesn't support this property or method: 'rsSQL.Execute'

Tags: sql, asp-classic, ado

heres my ASP:

```
sql="select * from empPac where empIdent='" & empIdent & "' and catalogIdent=" & catItem
Set rsSQL = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
rsSQL.Open sql,strConnect

sql="update empPac set sizeChartIdent=" & newSize & " where empPacIdent=" & rsSQL("empPacIdent")
rsSQL.Execute(sql)
```

now the problem is that it is throwing the following error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'rsSQL.Execute'
```

i cant figure out why

Comment: Hello, sql injection vulnerability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do the `Execute` method on the query, you have to do it on the connection instead.

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open strConnect

conn.Execute(sql)
```